# Center the content horizontally when the device is rotated in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xib, uiinterfaceorientation

I am new to iOS development. I have created a login screen using **xib** file. I have placed the contents aligned horizontally. But when I rotate the device the alignment is going off. Not sure how to stick to the same alignment when the device is rotated.

Please refer to the images for both scenario. Any advise is appreciated.

**When the device is rotated**

[image]

**When the device is in normal mode**

[image]

Comment: Please make time and read this [Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)... if you want to achieve this programmatically, show us what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

There' s a constraint, in "Align" that says "Horizontally in Container"
That's what you need
[image]

Comment: I can see that option if i use the storyboard, but when i use the xib file, it is not available.

Comment: So your xib file should have autolayout turned off: File inspector, "use autolayout" unchecked

Comment: Thanks, I enabled the "use auto layout", but when i set the horizontally in container, every elements are moving on top of another. I want the whole 4 items together to be aligned centred. Not each item independently.

Comment: You have now to add constraint for each of the elements, vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

u can add your fields into a UIView if you want their size to be fixed , then just add Horizontal Constraint to this UIView and set UIView size, then all elements will just follow their parent view